# Javascript: xmlhttpRequest Object How to handle one asynchronous request at a time

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a question on the xmlhttprequest object.
Let's say I create a xmlhttprequest object X to handle a user's request(asynchronously) to the server. For some reason, the server take 15 seconds to response. During those 15 seconds, if the user click on another button, how am I going about to determine the existence of the the first xmlhttprequest object I created in order to act accordingly (either telling the user that he/she needs to wait for the first request to finish or cancel it and continue with the second one.)

In short term, I need to know whether there is any request is being processed in order to handle another request.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag in the initial call and then clear it in the response.  Be sure to also clear it in the error callback if applicable to the framework you're using.

```
var callInProgress = false;

...

function callSever() {
    callInProgress = true;
    ...
}

function responseHandler() {
    ...
    callInProgress = false;
}

function errorHandler() {
    ...
    callInProgress = false;
}
```